# the value is not storing properly in an array

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

i have a define_Variable.sql file and contains

```
DEFINE T_SCHEMA='HR';
```

2) Create_table.sql

@define_variable.sql

```
DECLARE 
        TYPE table_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
         table_list table_array;
         l_query varchar2(500);
         is_exst number :=0;
         nt_exst number :=0;

        BEGIN
              l_query:= 'select  TABLE_NAME from DBA_tables WHERE OWNER = :OWNER and TABLE_NAME IN (''employee'',''appraisal'')';

execute immediate l_query BULK COLLECT INTO table_list USING '&T_SCHEMA' ;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Tables to be deployed is :'||table_list.count);

IF 'employee' member of table_list THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('employee TABLE ALREADY EXISTS');

         ELSE
           Execute Immediate(' create table employee( id number,name varchar2(50))');
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('employee TABLE created');
end if;
end;
/
```

when i execute the script, it will check for the table exists condition, and if exists , it will show the message as 'already exists' else, it will create a table.
so any number of time, my script can be executed without throwing error.

Now, the problem is, when i ran the script, it is throwing error as name already exists, the count of the array table_list.count is getting displayed as zero. It is going to else condition instead of IF condition.what could be the reason?

Comment: Why specify a schema name when checking whether the table already exists, but not when creating the table? It will create it in the current schema, which might not be the same as `&T_SCHEMA`. If it will always be the current schema you can simplify the code as you don't need the variable. Or simplify it even more by just attempting to create the table regardless and handling the _ORA-00955 name is already used_ exception as needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
create table employee( id number,name varchar2(50))
```

the table name is [not a quoted identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm) (which is good!), and the object name in the data dictionary will be the uppercase equivalent `EMPLOYEE`.

When you query the data dictionary the name needs to match that case:

```
l_query:= 'select  TABLE_NAME from DBA_tables WHERE OWNER = :OWNER and TABLE_NAME IN (''EMPLOYEE'',''APPRAISAL'')';
```

And when you look in the collection it also needs to be uppercase:

```
IF 'EMPLOYEE' member of table_list THEN
```

Your `USING` clause also looks wrong; the

```
USING '.&T_SCHEMA.' ;
```

means it will look for an owner value of `'.HR'`, rather than just `'HR'`, and unless you've made some effort to create a new schema with a dot in the name (as a quoted identifier) there will be no objects with that owner. You've used a trailing dot to - presumably - terminate the substitution variable name, which is fine but not strictly required here. You should not have a leading dot though:

```
USING '&T_SCHEMA.' ;
```

So at the moment you're populating your collection using both owner name and table names that don't exist, because they don't match what is actually in the data dictionary.

Comment: HI Alex, thanks for the comments, I tried with upper case, but it is not working. my real time project has over 15 tables and the array is showing empty despite some table already exists.

Comment: Did you fix the leading dot in the substitution too? If you have `set verify on` you can see exactly what the substitution is doing.

Comment: wow , it works, i believe its the mistake of using the trailing dots, sorted my problem Alex. Many thanks

Comment: [The *trailing* dot is OK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref458) - though not necessary. The leading dot is not OK.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use below to achieve your goal:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE table_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (200);
   table_list   table_array;

   l_query      VARCHAR2 (500);
   is_exst      NUMBER := 0;
   nt_exst      NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   l_query :=
      'select  TABLE_NAME from DBA_tables WHERE OWNER = :OWNER and TABLE_NAME IN (''EMPLOYEE'',''appraisal'')';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query BULK COLLECT INTO table_list USING '&T_SCHEMA.';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
      'Total Tables to be deployed is :' || table_list.COUNT);

  for i in 1..table_list.count
  loop
    IF table_list(i) = 'EMPLOYEE' THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('employee TABLE ALREADY EXISTS');       
     ELSE
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         (' create table employee( id number,name varchar2(50))');

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('employee TABLE created');
   END IF;

  end loop;
--
-- IF 'employee' MEMBER OF table_list
--   THEN
--      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('employee TABLE ALREADY EXISTS');
--   ELSE      
--      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
--         (' create table employee( id number,name varchar2(50))');
--
--      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('employee TABLE created');
--   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: If both `employee` and `appraisal` exist, the table count will be 2; assuming they're in that order, when `i=1` it will see that employee already exists and just report that. When `i=2` the value will be `'APPRAISAL'`, so it will still try to create the employee table again.

Comment: @XING, Thanks for the help

Comment: @AlexPoole.I guess OP has just asked for an example that why he created the employee table dynamically. In real scenario it should be dynamic.

Comment: @AnishGopinath..Nevertheless what Alex told is correct, I just gave an alternative to your work. Whatever you have done is also correct.